# Why is void pointer different from reference value?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, reference

```
class Class1
{
    int data;
    int *dataPtr;
}

int main()
{
     Class1 object;
     Class1 *objectPtr = &object;
     object.data = 1100;
     object.dataPtr = &(object.data)

     std::cout << object.dataPtr << std::endl;  //0x22aaa4
     std::cout << (void *) (object.data) << std::endl;  //0x1b198
     std::cout << (void *) &(object.data) << std::endl;  //0x22aaa4
```

Why is `(void *) (object.data)` different from `object.dataPtr`?

if I want to copy value from somewhere else to `object.data` using memcpy, which memory location do I use?

`memcpy( (void *) (object.data), source, size);` or

`memcpy( (void *) &(object.data), source, size);`

Thanks!

Comment: One you are converting an integer into a void*, one you are obtaining the address of that integer.

Comment: I don't see any references here.

Comment: This question is incredibly confusing. For a start, you never even use `objectPtr`. Secondly, it's not valid C++.

Comment: Finally, your middle output is wrong. It is in fact 1100 in hex, or `0x44c`, on all systems. (Though speaking theoretically, you've invoked UB there.)

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/050a0eae9d5ba8c7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `(void *) (object.data)` reinterprets the numeric value of `data` as a pointer, so it could have any value; and doing anything with it causes undefined behaviour. (As noted in the comments, one would expect it to be be `0x44c`, if the implementation-defined cast simply uses the numeric value 1100 as an address and the undefined behaviour doesn't cause any surprises.)

The address of `object.data` is `&object.data`.

If you used a safer cast or, in the case of `memcpy`, an implicit conversion, then the compiler would prevent this dodgy conversion:

```
static_cast<void *>(object.data)    // ERROR: int->pointer conversion
static_cast<void *>(&object.data)   // OK: pointer conversion

memcpy(object.data, source, size);  // ERROR: int where pointer expected
memcpy(&object.data, source, size); // OK: pointer converts to void*
```

In general, avoid C-style casts. And `memcpy`. And pointers.

Comment: No, (void*)(object.data) could not have any value, it ought to be 0x00044c which is the numeric value of 1100.  And, in fact, that's precisely the value that it has, if you fix the errors in the posted code fragment and run it.  (As I did for my answer.)

Comment: @MikeNakis: The conversion is implementation-defined, and using it is undefined behaviour, so it could have any value. Although I didn't notice it had been set to a particular value; you're right that that's the most likely value.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, it makes sense now. This was a pseudo code to represent the actual code. The actual code had `object.data = 111000;` that's why it output 0x1b198. I didn't realize it was the hex value when I posted this.

Answer (score 0):

This question is bogus.  The code would not even compile without first fixing syntax errors.

Once you get it to compile, **it produces exactly the expected output**, and not what the OP says it produces.

Here: http://ideone.com/qXWkGF

```
Success time: 0 memory: 3096 signal:0
0xbfbd5888
0x44c
0xbfbd5888
```

Comment: Sorry, I only meant it to be a pseudo code. The actual code does something similar to what I posted, but I just wanted a bare bone code for simplicity.